# Saving CookieStore in http client service

Tags: java, android, cookies

I have a Service for my Android app that performs HTTP calls. The Service stores cookies in a CookieStore. I am trying to find a way to persist the CookieStore but I haven't been successful. I don't want the user to log in every time to receive a new CookieStore.

I tried to use SharedPreferences to store the CookieStore as a string, but I can't re-construct the CookieStore with a String.

Has anyone else had success in persisting a CookieStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own [`CookieStore` implementation](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-httpclient-users/200904.mbox/%3Cb6b1d0ad0904081352q3e838aatebbf79aa53b1406c@mail.gmail.com%3E). Bear in mind that HttpClient isn't an Android-specific technology, so you will find some documentation over at the [Apache site](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html) (see section 3.7).

Comment: thanks mark. looked at the documentation more closely, i ended up writing out the entire cookiestore as a string to sharedprefs. then when reading the string back in i had to parse out each cookie manually

Answer (score 7):

There is a nice library for handling various aspects of http requests, among them persisting cookies in the shared preferences: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

(you can use the full lib or just the the two classes needed for cookie persistence)